# JavaScript - Toggle CSS colors with plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I'm trying to change the colors of a form text field back and forth, using plain javascript. Can somebody help?

I can change the color once but not back

Here is what I have done

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function color() {
                var x = document.getElementById("currID");
                if(x.style.color="red") {
                    x.style.color="blue";
                 }    
                }

            }
        </script>

        <input type="button" value="Click Me" id="testButton" onclick="color()" />

        <form method="get" action="getresult.php">

            <p>Current ID: <input id="currID" class="a" type="text" name="currID" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Request new ID"/></p>


        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
                .main {
                    color:black;
                }
                .a {
                    color:red;
                }
            </style>
```

Comment: what about a 2nd if? if you must do it this way ofcourse.

Comment: @Patrick with the second if, it doesn't change it back - i must be doing something wrong but I dont know what it is

Comment: @GDesigns what are you doing to change it back?

Comment: @Orifjon- nothing right now, but I cannot figure it out using the if statement - which is why i asked for help

Comment: Add change color to red on else caption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript</title>

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
           function color() {
            var x = document.getElementById("currID");
                if(x.className == "main"){
                    x.className = "a";
                } else {
                    x.className = "main";
                }
            }
    </script>

    <input type="button" value="Click Me" id="testButton" onclick="color()" />

    <form method="get" action="getresult.php">

        <p>Current ID: <input id="currID" class="a" type="text" name="currID" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Request new ID"/></p>


    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.main {
    color:black;
}
.a {
    color:red;
}
</style>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/a5rxoh03/

Comment: Oh perfect! I couldn't figure it out, but this makes a lot of sense Thanks

Comment: Oh you wanted to toggle css classes, not css color. Oh well.

Comment: @Basem - Just one question, why do you check if the class is main first? shouldnt it be "a" first?

Comment: The same, you can test it

Comment: This was great! I struggled on my own for hours, not really understanding why hex values and rgb values wouldn't work. I switched to toggling class names and voila! It works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Specifically to your issue, and why it didn't work, is because when adding a 2nd IF, you just reveresed the result.

Check out this fiddle, it will change the input field of the "currID" as requested from blue to red and vice verca.

https://jsfiddle.net/0rnnqe3y/

This is the JS :

```
         function color() {
            var x = document.getElementById("currID");
            console.log(x.style.color == "red");
            if(x.style.color=="red") {

                x.style.color="blue";
                return;

             };
            if(x.style.color=="blue"){
               x.style.color="red";
               return;
            }   
}
```